# I just want to pull all the active/inactive tenants details from WSO2 which a particular user has access

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Do we have an WSO2 internal API which returns the user specific active tenants information.
I just want to pull all the active/inactive tenants details from WSO2 which a particular user has access.
Can someone please share an API for that?
If the API is not available then How to create custom API for this purpose.

Comment: What is the product what is the version? There is no data sharing between tenants, so what do you mean by "I just want to pull all the active/inactive tenants details from WSO2 which a particular user has access".

Comment: Product is WSO2 3.2. I just want to pull the tenant information from WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 Admin services for this. First add the following to deployment.toml

```
[admin_service.wsdl]
enable = true
```

Then you should be able to use the `getAllTenants` method in `RemoteTenantManagerService` admin service. You can read more on how to use Admin services from [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/wso2-admin-services/).

Following is a sample request and response.

[image]